React Query wont invalidate and re-fetch at the initial mutation call. but if I defocus my browser window and focus again, it starts working correctly
I have a react query problem. the very first edit I submit does not invalidate the data. but if I defocus and refocus the browser window it starts invalidating correctly after each mutation without the need to defocus. why is that?
`    const queryClient = useQueryClient()
const fetchCaseData = async () => {
    const caseService = await GetCaseService()
    return caseService.getCaseWithAssets(projectId, caseId)
}

useQuery(
    [projectId, caseId],
    fetchCaseData,
    {
        enabled: !!projectId && !!caseId,
        onSuccess: (result) => {
            console.log("Case data fetched successfully:", result)
        },
        onError: (error: Error) => {
            console.error("Error fetching data:", error)
            setSnackBarMessage("Case data not found. Redirecting back to project")
            navigate("/")
        },
    },
)

const { data: apiData } = useQuery<Components.Schemas.CaseWithAssetsDto | undefined>(
    [projectId, caseId],
    () => queryClient.getQueryData([projectId, caseId]),
    {
        enabled: !!projectId && !!caseId,
        initialData: () => queryClient.getQueryData([projectId, caseId]),
    },
)

const mutation = useMutation(
    async ({ serviceMethod }: {
        projectId: string,
        caseId: string,
        resourceId?: string,
        resourceProfileId?: string,
        wellId?: string,
        drillingScheduleId?: string,
        serviceMethod: object,
    }) => serviceMethod,
    {
        onSuccess: (
            results: any,
            variables,
        ) => {
            const { projectId, caseId } = variables
            queryClient.invalidateQueries([projectId, caseId])
        },
        onError: (error: any) => {
            console.error("Failed to update data:", error)
        },
    },
)


const updateCase = async (
    projectId: string,
    caseId: string,
    resourcePropertyKey: ResourcePropertyKey,
    value: any,
    resourceObject?: ResourceObject,
) => {
    const caseService = await GetCaseService()
    const existingDataInClient: Components.Schemas.CaseWithAssetsDto | undefined = queryClient.getQueryData([projectId, caseId])

    const caseObjectFromClient = existingDataInClient?.case

    const updatedData = resourceObject || { ...caseObjectFromClient, [resourcePropertyKey]: value }
    const serviceMethod = caseService.updateCase(projectId, caseId, updatedData as Components.Schemas.CaseDto)

    try {
        return await mutation.mutateAsync({
            projectId,
            caseId,
            serviceMethod,
        })
    } catch (error) {
        return false
    }
}`

I am trying to submit data edits. when I do, I need to refetch from the api, because some of the values are generated in the back end and needs to replace the old one. this re-fetching process does not happen on first mutation attempt, but it does work as expected if I de-focus the window once after the failed attempt. then it works as expected every time going forward
